# Will removeEventListener remove HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I haven't seen anyone else ask this question, and I'm curious if an attribute event handler will be removed via JavaScript `removeEventListener`.

```
<video id='myVideo' src='blah.mp4' onended='window.onMyVideoEnded'></video>

document.querySelector('#myVideo').removeEventListener('ended', window.onMyVideoEnded);
```

Will this code prevent the listener from being invoked, even though it's 'hardcoded' inline on the HTML element?

Comment: I dont think that will work. "The removeEventListener() method removes an event handler that has been attached with the addEventListener() method."

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

Comment: @victor feel free to post the answer with an example, that sounds right to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the event will still go.

```js
window.clickFunction = function() {
  alert('Clicked!')
}

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('Loaded!')
  document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', window.clickFunction)
}
```

```html
<button onclick = 'window.clickFunction()' id = 'button'>Test</button>
```

Comment: So what are ways to prevent the event?

Comment: document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {}